# Can't rerun child_process.spawn() after last process ends

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

I have a command `telnet` that recives as parameter an IP and Port, and it gets a log from a remote program while running. What I'm doing: node will create a process `telnet`, filter the log for some informations and try to rerun `telnet` in case it closes. At first time it runs nicely, but when the I close the remote program, node desn't try rerun `telnet`.

```
'use strict';

const { spawn } = require( 'child_process' );
const cmd = 'telnet';
const params = ['10.10.10.10', '1010'];
var telnet;

let isRunning = false;

connect();
connectionCheckRoutine()

telnet.stdout.on( 'data', data => {
  console.log( `> ${data}` );
  isRunning = true;
} );

telnet.stderr.on('data', data => {
  console.log(`err: ${data}` );
} );

telnet.on('close', code => {
  console.log( `child process exited with code ${code}` );
  isRunning = false;
} );

function connect(){
  telnet = spawn( cmd, params);
}

async function connectionCheckRoutine(){
  while(true){
    await sleep(5000);
    if(!isRunning){
      console.log('Reconnecting...');
      connect();
    }
  }
}

async function sleep(millis) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, millis));
}
```

I expected that after process ends I could try reconnect using the child_process.spawn() again, but nothing happens if I call spawn() once more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue happens because the event listeners that you register for the child process events do not re-register when `telnet` variable is overwritten with a new child process.

Try to move the event handlers registration inside the `connect` function to ensure that the handlers are re-registered every time a child process is spawned:

```
function connect(){
  const telnet = spawn(cmd, params);

  telnet.stdout.on( 'data', data => {
    console.log( `> ${data}` );
    isRunning = true;
  });

  telnet.stderr.on('data', data => {
    console.log(`err: ${data}` );
  });

  telnet.on('close', code => {
    console.log( `child process exited with code ${code}` );
    isRunning = false;
  });
}
```